# Principale value of complex integral

Tags: integration, cauchy-principal-value

I'm trying to calculate an integral of the form:

$$  \textrm{Int}=PP\int_{1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x ^2 a^2 + 2 a x+ 2}{\sqrt{x ^2-1} \left[\left(b^2-c^2\right)x ^2 -b^2\right]} e^{-ax}\, dx $$

where $a>0,\,b>0,\,c>0$  are reals and $PP$ is the Cauchy principale value of the integral.

please, is this true  for my $ \textrm{Int} $,

$$  PP\int_{1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x ^2 a^2 + 2 a x+ 2}{\sqrt{x ^2-1} \left[\left(b^2-c^2\right)x ^2 -b^2\right]} e^{-ax}\, dx = \int_{1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x ^2 a^2 + 2 a x+ 2}{\sqrt{x ^2-1} \left[\left(b^2-c^2\right)x ^2 -b^2\right]} e^{-ax}\, dx $$

how to calculte it please ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the integrand may have a pole between $1$ and $\infty$, so that the integral itself diverges.

If $b>c$, then the denominator vanishes at $x=q$, where
$$q=\frac{b}{\sqrt{b^2-c^2}}$$  So the "principal value" means do an integral
$$
\int_1^{q-\epsilon} + \int_{q+\epsilon}^\infty
$$
and take the limit as $\epsilon \to 0^+$.

Comment: is it achievable?

Comment: is there any way to calculate it symbolically?

Comment: A suggestion please?